# Swift 2.0 Going between String and Enum:String

Tags: string, swift, casting, enums

Unrelated to the problem however it arose because i'm parsing JSON data and i thought it would be more easy if my enum were of type Sting

so I have this definition:

```
enum colors: String {
    case kRed = "red"
    case kBlue = "blue"
    case kGreen = "green"
}
```

while parsing values from json i get a string, lets say "red"
I know I can make a switch on the string and look at the rawValue() of the enum, however is there a more easy way to go from string value red to colors.kRed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let myColor = colors(rawValue: "red")
```

There's more detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) under *Initializing from a Raw Value*

Comment: ohh and that even returns an optional to account for my error, perfecto. Thank you